# SimpleAdapter dynamically modify listitem

Tags: android, simpleadapter

I am using a custom adapter and changing the color of the items.

I need to modify only a specific item from a row.

I should do this through getview or any other efficient method for this?

Comment: At what moment do you need the item color to be modified?